# Where can I find driver Huawei MF171 3g modem in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, lubuntu

My Huawei MF171 3g modem has driver only for windows and not for Linux and I would to know: In which sites or applications or anything else could I find driver for my Huawei MF171 3g modem in lubuntu 16.04? Thank in advance !

Comment: Insert the modem and wait a minute. If Ubuntu shows a notification about **Mobile Broadband** modem detection then you won't need any additional driver; a generic driver is already included in your system. In that case you can create a dial-up connection and use internet. Though you can't use special functionalities of the modem like call/SMS.

Comment: @HattinGokbori87 theoretically one can. Such modems usually supply a virtual serial port, into which you can write AT aka Hayes commands to make calls and manage SMS messages. But you wouldn't want doing that manually, and I don't know if there's somewhere an UI to it.